# Full Backup of non-rooted devices (Android version 2.3.X and below)

Tags: backup

This question is NOT a duplicate of [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices) question but of an follow-up because the answers over there does not provided any solution for Android version 2.3.X and below.

In that question - [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices), User `ryan-conrad` provided a solution for Android version for 4.X devices. Another user `sachin-shekhar` mention using the Odin but from my understanding, Odin is used for flashing and not backup and also many people feel that Odin is still not stable and it is not open source.

Please note that the following requirements:

```
- Full backup of the phone
- No voiding the warranty
- No rooting before backup
```

So, are there any solution to perform Full backup for non-rooted Android version 2.3.X and below devices?

Comment: Good luck, Jack! In my question (which you linked) I especially asked for a widely applyable solution, *at least on Gingerbread* (quote from there). As the question even had a bounty, I'd say a solution, if existing, would have turned up. But who knows... Will be interesting to see :) So again: Good luck...

Comment: I just come by thread and the linked thread cause I am searching the same thing at the moment. It's true that it's hard or rather rare to find a solution of having any `adb` function to run without rooting the phone itself. I think my best advice is to create a backup function other than `adb`.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing for Honeycomb (3.x)