# Backup Android 2.3.6 app data before rooting

Tags: backup, samsung-galaxy-y

I want to create a backup of application data (game highscores etc.) for Android version 2.3.6, before I try to root. How to do it?

Helium (Carbon) and Z4Root aren't compatible with my OS version / device.

Comment: Not a chance: To backup app data before Android 4.0, you need root. Except when the apps themselves offer a backup feature (be it export/import or Google Cloud Backup integration).

Comment: [How can data on an unrooted phone be backed up?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12470/981), [How do I perform a full pre-rooting backup of an Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5667/981), [Full Backup of non-rooted devices (Android version 2.3.X and below)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33479/981)

Comment: Yupp: 1+2 basically say what I wrote (just with some more details), 3 has no answer (and I just marked it duplicate of 2 -- which I will now do for this one as well).